# Automate App Service diagnostic logging to Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to automate the process of configuring Azure App Service to export diagnostic logs to Azure Storage, but I'm running into something I don't quite understand. I can take the following steps to get it working.

1. I configure diagnostic logging in the Azure Portal, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#enablediag). Everything looks good. I can see the logs being populated in the storage containers.
2. Using [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), I navigate to the `config/logs` resource and observe the JSON:

   ```
   "applicationLogs": {
     ...
     "azureBlobStorage": {
       "level": "Information",
       "sasUrl": "https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?sv=YYYY-MM-DD&sr=c&sig=<sig>&st=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ&se=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ&sp=rwdl",
       "retentionInDays": null
     }
   },
   "httpLogs": {
     ...
     "azureBlobStorage": {
       "sasUrl": "https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?sv=YYYY-MM-DD&sr=c&sig=<sig>&st=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ&se=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ&sp=rwdl",
       "retentionInDays": null,
       "enabled": true
     }
   },
   ```
3. I can then hard-code the `sasUrl` values in an ARM template with a `config/logs` resource, and everything still works. I can verify this by first deleting the storage containers and disabling diagnostic logs, then redeploying the ARM template.

After getting that working, I attempt to use the ARM template function `listAccountSas` to generate a new SAS for the storage resource. However, the resulting SAS has a slightly different format than the one I obtained from Azure Resource Explorer: `sv=YYYY-MM-DD&ss=b&srt=s&sp=rwdl&st=YYYY-MM-DDTHH%3AMM%3ASS.0000000Z&se=YYYY-MM-DDTHH%3AMM%3ASS.0000000Z&spr=https&sig=<sig>`.

So what's going on here. How is the portal generating the SAS? Is the `listAccountSas` function generating a token that will work in its place? Is there even a way to automate this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I known, the ARM template function [listAccountSas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys-and-listvalue) only can list value, it can't create new vaule.And you can't create a sasToken within the template. I suggest you use Powershell to create a sasToken, store it in Azure KeyVault, and refer that KeyVault secret in the template. 
Regarding how to use cert in the template, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter).

```
$name = "your account"
$password = "your password"
$RGname = "your resource group name"
$accountNmae  ="your Storage Account name"
$containerNmae ="your container name"
$keyvaultNmae ="your Key Vault name"
$certName = "your cert name"
$location = ""

# login Azure 
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $mycreds

#create Azure storage SAS URL
$account = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RGname  -Name $accountNmae
$SASURL = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Container $containerNmae -Context $account.Context -Permission rwdl -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddYears(1) -FullUri

#create key vault
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $keyVaultName -resourceGroupName $RGname -Location $location -EnabledForTemplateDeployment
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -UserPrincipalName $name -PermissionsToSecrets set,delete,get,list

#create cert
$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString $SASURL -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultNmae -Name "test" -SecretValue $secretvalue
```